# Commandline Window not closing after TASKKILL

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I use the command

```
call start startComponent.bat
```

to start an application in a seperate window. When I want to stop it, I run another batch file with the commands:

```
FOR /F "tokens=2" %%A IN ('tasklist /v ^| findstr /i "startComponent"') DO SET PID=%%A
TASKKILL /F /PID %PID%
```

This has the desired task of killing the process, but the command prompt that was opened to run the component is not closed automatically.

As an aside, if I want to manually kill the process with CTRL-C, it prompts "Terminate batch job (Y/N)?". Could this have something to do with the window not being closed?

EDIT:

startCompoonent.bat starts a java process. My new problem is how to kill the specific instance of java.exe. If I do taskkill /f java.exe, it will kill all java.exe processes. Is there a way to start java with a name (i.e. startComponent.exe)?

DOUBLE EDIT:

Figured it out.

```
FOR /F "tokens=2" %%A IN ('tasklist /v ^| findstr /i "startComponent"') DO SET PID=%%A
TASKKILL /F /PID %PID%
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%A IN ('C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\jps -v ^| findstr /i "ComponentMain"') DO SET PID=%%A
TASKKILL /F /PID %PID%
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `call start startComponent.bat` what if you tried something along the lines of this:

```
call start cmd.exe /C startComponent.bat`
```

Comment: What purpose does that serve? I needed to have "startComponent.bat" in the title of the window so that I could kill it later.

Comment: Sorry. It seems you don't need this. I use the cmd /C a lot because it will make cmd exit when the batch file is completed. But you don't need this in this case. When I test this, your code works fine on my machine, but my startComponent.bat is just sleeping in a loop. You probably need to taskkill whatever process the startComponent.bat is starting.

Answer (score 0):

On my system (Win 7) your task run correct and command line window with startComponent.bat is closed after taskkill.

Are you run command "call start startComponent.bat" from command line or from other bat-file?

EDIT:

1) Try run simple "start startComponent.bat" without "call".

2) Try "start /B startComponent.bat".